# Can you get live wallpapers on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: desktop-background

I would like to have a live wallpaper on my desktop but I don't know how.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Live wallpaper as in animated wallpaper or slideshow ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes we can ..follow the steps:

Add PPA for live wallpaper

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily
```

Install `livewallpaper`

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install livewallpaper
```

Install `livewallpaper-config` and `livewallpaper-indicator`

```
sudo apt-get install livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator
```

All done. Now type `live wallpaper` in dash:

[image]

And select wallpaper of your choice like this. Trust me its moving :p

[image]

Comment: @TheEpicstarlord,  `sudo apt-get update` update your local lists of available packages from the repositories.

Comment: Remember - Preferences is for changing the live wallpaper